# Select data using websql service angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, web-sql

I am trying to  select  data from  a websql table  using the  websql service  and display on the screen using ng-repeat.but i can't  display the data.

---

```
 $scope.db.selectAll("project").then(function(results) {
 $scope.projects = [];
  for(var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
 $scope.projects.push(results.rows.item(i));
 console.log(results.rows.item(i));
 }
 })
```

---

```
 <li ng-repeat="project in projects" id="project"> {{projects}} </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're suppose to write "project" instead "projects", like:

```
 <li ng-repeat="project in projects" id="project"> {{project}} </li>
```

Also if you're having any key in projects let's say "name" then you can show something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="project in projects" id="project">{{project.name}}</li>
```

Hope it'll help you.